# Generar Código QR entre Fragmentos

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment, qr

soy nuevo en esto de `Android` y ahora estoy haciendo un `Scanner QR` pero solo utilizo puros `fragments` y eh revisado en todo internet como hacerlo, logre que salga la camara y capture la imagen del código pero no me muestra ningun resultado, siempre sale en blanco y no se por que... ayuda por favor.
Les dejo aca el Código que estoy haciendo (el ultimo de todos) por que intente muchos pero ninguno me devuelve el resultado de la lectura

**1.-** En un fragmento (Frg_Asistencia) llamo a otro fragmento(SKM) este ultimo va a servir de pantalla y mandara el mensaje de vuelta a (Frg_Asistencia)

**--Frg_Asistencia:**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        JAsisRH = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.frg__asistencia, container, false );
    System.out.println ( "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaRECURSOS HUMANOS:" + Tim );
    FotoR = (TextView) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.tvFotoR );
    NombreR = (TextView) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.tvNombreR );
    PuestoR = (TextView) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.tvPuestoR );
    AreaR = (TextView) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.tvAreaR );
    ContenidoR = (TextView) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.tvContenidoR );
    PersonalR = (EditText) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.etCodPersonalR );
    CodeQR = (Button) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.btnCodEpiR );
    Buscar = (Button) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.btnBuscarR );


    CodeQR.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bnsacam= new skm ();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_main, bnsacam);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();



        }
    } );

    return JAsisRH;
}
```

---

**2.-** Fragmento SKM (captura la imagen -QR):

```
public class skm extends Fragment {
private String codeFormat,codeContent;
private final String noResultErrorMsg = "No scan data received!";


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );

    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this.getActivity()).forSupportFragment(this);
    // use forSupportFragment or forFragment method to use fragments instead of activity
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setCameraId(0);  // especificar una camara
    integrator.initiateScan();
    System.out.println ("00000000000000001111111111111111");
}
/**
 * function handle scan result
 * @param requestCode scanned code
 * @param resultCode  result of scanned code
 * @param intent intent
 */

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    ScanResultReceiver parentActivity = (ScanResultReceiver) getContext ();

    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //we have a result
        System.out.println ("00000000000000002222222222222222");
        codeContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        codeFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        // send received data
        parentActivity.scanResultData(codeFormat,codeContent);

    }else{
        // send exception
        parentActivity.scanResultData(new NoScanResultException(noResultErrorMsg));
        System.out.println ("000000000000000033333333333333333");
    }

   }
}
```

---

**3.-** Hago una interface que me servira como un puente para que se conecte y mande la respuesta del mensaje (ScanResultReceiver):

```
public interface ScanResultReceiver {
    /**
     * function to receive scanresult
     * @param codeFormat format of the barcode scanned
     * @param codeContent data of the barcode scanned
     */
    public void scanResultData(String codeFormat, String codeContent);

    public void scanResultData(NoScanResultException noScanData);
}
```

---

**4.-** Creo una clase (NoScanResultException):

```
public class NoScanResultException extends Exception {
    public NoScanResultException() {}
    public NoScanResultException(String msg) { super(msg); }
    public NoScanResultException(Throwable cause) { super(cause); }
    public NoScanResultException(String msg, Throwable cause) { super(msg, cause); }
}
```

---

**5.-** Regresando al primer Fragmento donde quiero que se muestre la respuesta -- en la parte superior  implemento  y coloco:

```
@Override
    public void scanResultData(String codeFormat, String codeContent) {
        ContenidoR.setText(codeContent);
        System.out.println ("00000000000000004444444444444444444");
        Toast.makeText (getActivity (),"llegueeeeeeeeeeeee",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ();
    }

    @Override
    public void scanResultData(NoScanResultException noScanData) {
        System.out.println ("00000000000000005555555555555555555555");
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity (),
                "ERROR: Mensaje no Recibido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

---

Y cuando lo ejecuto si abre la camara, captura la imagen y queda hasta ahi nada más, cuando tiene que devolver el resultado.
Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, le estaría muy agradecida, o si tuvieran un código más pequeño, ya que el otro proyecto si lo realice pero en una Actividad y el código en muy pequeño en verdad.
Aca también les dejo lo que me sale de error, el cual indica

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.M_Menu cannot be cast to
>   sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.ScanResultReceiver

y el M_menu es mi unico Activity de toda la app:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android, PID: 20186
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=114910, result=0, data=null} to
>   activity
>   {sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android/sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.M_Menu}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.M_Menu
>   cannot be cast to sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.ScanResultReceiver
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4349)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4391)
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.M_Menu cannot be cast to
>   sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.ScanResultReceiver
>                         at sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android.skm.onActivityResult(skm.java:39)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:160)
>                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7449)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4342)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4391) 
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
>   I/chatty: uid=10085(sie.progrsistepinsa.sie_android) identical 7 lines
>   W/ViewRootImpl[CaptureActivity]: Cancelling event due to no window
>   focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0,
>   metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=66108843,
>   downTime=66107419, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 } I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 20186 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el detalle esta en tu delegado para pasar el código escaneado. Si lo que deseas es enviar la información a tu Activity el código sería el siguiente:

1era opción

Llamarlo desde el mismo fragment

```
public class Frg_Asistencia extends Fragment {
MainActivity context;
TextView textView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    context = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    View JAsisRH = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.frg__asistencia, container, false );
    Button CodeQR = (Button) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.btnCodEpiR );
    textView = (TextView) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.text_qr );

    CodeQR.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator scannerIntegrator = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(Frg_Asistencia.this);
            scannerIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan barcode");
            scannerIntegrator.setCameraId(0);
            scannerIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            scannerIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
            scannerIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    } );

    return JAsisRH;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (scanningResult != null) {
        //we have a result
        System.out.println ("Codigo:"+scanningResult);
        textView.setText(scanningResult.getContents());

    }else{
        // send exception
        //parentActivity.scanResultData(new NoScanResultException(noResultErrorMsg));
        System.out.println ("000000000000000033333333333333333");
    }

}
}
```

2nda opción

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   //Result from Camera by scan Barcode
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (scanningResult != null) {
          //we have a result
           System.out.println("Codigo =>" + scanningResult);
           String codeContent = scanningResult.getContents();
           String codeFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
           // send received data

           Fragment fragmentdisplay = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
           if (fragmentdisplay instanceof Frg_Asistencia) {
               ((Frg_Asistencia) fragmentdisplay).recibirQR(codeContent);
           }
      } else {
        System.out.println("000000000000000033333333333333333");
      }
   }
}
```

y tu fragmento

```
public class Frg_Asistencia extends Fragment {
    MainActivity context;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        View JAsisRH = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.frg__asistencia, container, false );
        Button CodeQR = (Button) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.btnCodEpiR );
        textView = (TextView) JAsisRH.findViewById ( R.id.text_qr );

        CodeQR.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(context);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
              integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setCameraId(0);  // especificar una camara
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        } );

        return JAsisRH;
    }

    public void  recibirQR(String qr) {
        System.out.print("Llego :" + qr);
        textView.setText(qr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero quiero enviar la información a otro Fragmento, osea el scanner esta en un fragmento y quiero que la informacion del scaneo me muestre en otro fragmento, ayuda

Comment: Hola , modifique la respuesta para que puedas recibir el dato en el fragmento Frg_Asistencia, espero sea de ayuda si no seguimos revisando.

Comment: Muchas gracias <3 me haz salvado la vida, en verdad que estaba estresada de que no me salía, gracias nuevamente <3.